# Trouble Plotting Polar Graph

Tags: python

I am working on my homework for my Python course and one of our questions requires us to plot the Bessel function in Cartesian coordinates and then Polar coordinates.
I am having trouble with the latter. The problem also requires us to mask any values of radius greater than 20 and any values of theta between .4 and -.4.
This is where I'm having issues. I feel like I am setting up the mask correctly, but I can't get the graph to look like the Cartesian version. Plotting both with pcolormesh.

[Picture of Code: Top is Cartesian / Bottom is Polar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGPFE.png)

In the polar I used u to define radius, j to define angle, and k equal to the Bessel function of radius 'u'. j0 represents the bessel function.

```
from scipy.special import j0, j1, jn
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
j = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 200)
u = np.linspace(0, 20, 200)
k = j0(u)
jmask = np.ma.masked_where((j<.4) & (j>-.4), j)
umask = np.ma.masked_greater(u, 20, copy=True)
U, J = np.meshgrid(umask, jmask)
plt.pcolormesh(J, U, j0(U))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In SO you must show the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware.

Comment: what is j0 here, if you add a code it's better you config all the functions/variables.